# How to index tensor with shape (batch_size, 200, 256) to obtain (batch_size, 1, 256) given list of index tensor with length = batch_size?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I have the output from LSTM layer with shape (batch_size, 200, 256) where 200 is the length of tokens sequence and 256 is LSTM output dimension.
I also have another tensor with shape (batch_size) which is the list of index of a token that I want to slice out from each sample sequence in a batch.

If the token index is not -1, I will slice out a token vector representation (length = 256). If the token index is -1, I will give out zero vector (length = 256).

The expected output result has shape (batch_size, 1, 256). How should I do that?

Thank you

Here is what I have tried so far

```
bidir = concatenate([forward, backward]) # shape = (batch_size, 200, 256) 
dropout = Dropout(params['dropout_rate'])(bidir)
def slice_by_tensor(x):
    matrix_to_slice = x[0]
    index_tensor = x[1]


    out_tensor = tf.where(index_tensor == -1, 
                          tf.zeros(tf.shape(tf.gather(matrix_to_slice, 
                                                      index_tensor, axis=1))), 
                          tf.gather(matrix_to_slice, index_tensor, axis=1))



    return out_tensor


representation_stack0 = Lambda(lambda x: slice_by_tensor(x))([dropout,stack_idx0]) 
# stack_idx0 shape is (batch_size) 
# I got output with shape (batch_size, batch_size, 256) with this code
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
a=tf.reshape(tf.range(2*3*4),shape=(2,3,4))
#     [[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
#        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
#        [ 8,  9, 10, 11]],

#      [[12, 13, 14, 15],
#      [16, 17, 18, 19],
#       [20, 21, 22, 23]]]

b=tf.constant([-1,2]) 

aa=tf.pad(a,[[0,0],[1,0],[0,0]]) 

bb=b+1 

index=tf.stack([tf.range(tf.size(b)),bb],axis=-1) 
res=tf.expand_dims(tf.gather_nd(aa, index),axis=1)
#[[[ 0,  0,  0,  0]],
#[[20, 21, 22, 23]]]
```

When index is -1, we need zeros like tensor. So we can first pad original tensor along the second axis. Then increase the indices by 1. After this, using `tf.gather_nd` will return the answer.